# mongodb not installing windows 7 64 bit

Tags: mongodb, installation

I have downloaded latest mongo and ran the setup file on windows 7 64 bit. But it's not moving further from the below screen.

[image]

Comment: found any solution? Same thing happening with me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:
1. Hit cancel
2.delete the c:\ program files \ mongodb folder 
3. Install the mongo setup again

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Mongo Compass which is selected(default) during installation that does not work for Windows 7 64 bit. Please cancel the installation remove the mongodb folder and start reinstalling.
During reinstall, uncheck the mongo compass (you have install it manually for Win 7 users). The link to download the compass is below (https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass).